# The link is not opening up in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code I am expecting the link should open up in a new tab but it is not happening how can I do the same?

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.min.js"></script>
<a href='inmedia.co.in' target='_blank'>
<video id='videojs-w0' class='video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered' width='640' height='264' poster='http://www.inmedia.co.in/platform/inmedia/frontend/web/screenimages/advertiser1 1.png' data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": true, "preload": "auto", "inactivityTimeout": 0, "controlBar": { "volumeMenuButton": true, "playToggle": false, "progressControl":false,"BigPlayButton": true } }'>
<source type='video/mp4' src='http://www.inmedia.co.in/platform/inmedia/frontend/web/uploadvideos/advertiser1 1.webm'>
<track src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/vtt/captions.vtt" kind="captions" srclang="en" label="English">
</video>
</a>
<script> var uid='181'; var aid='88'; var pid='178'; 
</script>
<script src="http://www.inmedia.co.in/platform/inmedia/frontend/web/scripts/js/ivctrack.js">
</script>
```

I am trying to wrap up the video element inside an href tag this code is being generated with php

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please help us to help you and format your code. It's currently one long, very unreadable line.

Comment: Please format that code onto multiple lines so we can read it.

Comment: @Attersson  There is a

Comment: now that it's formatted I can see...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change this

```
<link href="
```

to this,

```
<link target="_blank" href="
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: that link is just for css

Comment: anyway if I added double quote it is working as expected.

Comment: This answer doesn't know the difference between a `link` tag and a `a` tag.

Comment: trolled scrubs.